# How to clear storage, using react-native-mmkv-storage?

Tags: react-native, storage

I couldn't find it in https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-mmkv-storage
Do you have any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full document of react-native-mmkv-storage
you can find all related methods under general methods.

https://rnmmkv.vercel.app/#/generalmethods

Comment: I used this -   MMKV.clearStore();  Thanks!